# How can I delete an entire json object from an array of json objects and write it out to file?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Hello I'm trying to delete an entire object from an array of objects and rewrite the file out at the same time.

My object looks like this...

```
[
 {
  "name": "My Name",
  "menu": "My Menu",
  "content": "Some content about me"
 },
 {
  "name": "Another Name",
  "menu": "Another Menu",
  "content": "Some more content about me"
 }
]
```

I'm opening this file with node by using...

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

The user enters in name of the object they want to delete from the file and presses submit, it calls my handleSubmit function

```
handleSubmit(e) {
   let dialogName = this.state.title;       // name of object to be deleted
   dialogName = dialogName.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');
   dialogNmae = dialogName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dialogName.substr(1);

   let dataJson = fs.readFileSync('./app/data/MyData.json');
   let tempData = JSON.parse(dataJson);

   tempData = tempData.filter(obj => {
       return dialogName === obj.name;
      }).map((obj, index) => {
           obj.splice(0,3);
            return (
                <div>
                </div>
             );
      });

    tempData = JSON.stringify(tempData, null, 2);
    fs.writeFile('./app/data/MyData.json', tempData, finished);
}
```

My problem is it overwrites all of the data and leaves me with an empty data table.  I just want to delete one object, not all of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: The filter function removes the one that matches the test. So if you want a list with only the match not in the list you need to test that the name doesn't match.

```js
var data = '[{"name":"My Name","menu":"My Menu","content":"Some content"},{"name": "Another Name", "menu": "Another Menu", "content": "Some more content about me" }]';

var tempData = JSON.parse(data);

var dialogName = "My Name";
   
console.log(tempData);
   
tempData = tempData.filter(obj => {
     return dialogName !== obj.name;
  });
  
console.log(tempData);

tempData = JSON.parse(data);
tempData = tempData.filter(obj => {
         return "Not there?" !== obj.name;
      });

console.log(tempData);

// Not there removes all from the list? when logci inverted. 
tempData = JSON.parse(data);
tempData = tempData.filter(obj => {
         return "Not there?" === obj.name;
      });

console.log(tempData);
```

Second your `map` function doesn't make any sense! I thought you wanted json? whats with the`<div>` tags?

Comment: Ah yes, I had made a react component to add files and return them to the screen and tried to port over the function and forgot to remove the div return

Comment: Yeah this leaves the same problem I had before - an empty data.json file